# How cloudflare add-on feature of rate limiting work for free plan?

Tags: cloudflare

I am little confused with cloufflare's add-on features mentioned on https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/plans/.

> Quote: Take your performance and security even further with Cloudflare’s
>   paid add-ons for Free, Pro, and Business plans.

So they say I can buy add-ons even with free plan. Now one of the add-ons is a rate-limiting for requests which charges $.05 per 10K good requests. So if I don't buy this add-on, how will they charge per request, good or bad?

They say they protect users from DDoS attacks even on a free plan, so what is a point of buying rate-limiting feature? Is there a limit to requests/bandwidth for free plan users?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Comment: Rather than ask Cloudflare directly (where they could directly provide you an answer), you'd rather ask here, on the off chance someone from Cloudflare sees it and answers?

Comment: The "we are not customer support" phrase is an abbreviation for a much longer and often repeated argument which you are welcome to explore in much more detail and color on [meta] if you really want to understand how this site works and why this sort of question is incompatible with our mission. The short version of that is ... Machiavity is right.

Comment: @tripleee Stackoverflow do mention to not ask customer support related question. I never argued that is wrong. My objection is the tone of the message. Stackoverfllow gives mentor right to take actions but that does not include "say whatever you want".

Answer (score 2):

A DDoS attack and a rate-limiting are two completely different things, they can be complimentary, but one does not exclude the other.

The DDoS attack is usually (especially for the free plans) only for specific types of attacks, where the traffic is identifiably bad and often simply trying to consume your resources without expecting a response.

Rate-limiting on the other hand can be used for limiting the querying ability by specific users, for whatever reason (be it computation time, login protection, API resource management, etc.). These queries are possibly benign and/or valid, which won't trigger the DDoS protection (immediately at least, it may obviously).

> So if I don't buy this add-on, how will they charge per request, good or bad?
>
> They say they protect users from DDoS attacks even on a free plan, so what is a point of buying rate-limiting feature? Is there a limit to requests/bandwidth for free plan users?

They don't charge per request or bandwidth because they don't rate limit (up to extreme cases where they will force the website to bypass Cloudflare's proxy if there is impact on the network as a whole, which are very extreme and for the almost totality of users of the free plan are out of reach) normally. If you want to rate-limit an endpoint then you buy the add-on (with the possibility of paying after the initial 10k good reqs/month per account).

Note that the higher the plan the lower the time intervals you can set, on the free plan is an higher interval than on Pro which is higher than Business.

More info: https://www.cloudflare.com/rate-limiting/

Comment: Thanks for your reply and welcome to "Stackoverflow"! I do understand rate limiting can be used in variety of use cases and DDoS being one of them. Now Cloudflare have their own algorithms to detect DDoS attacks based on usual user behavior. My assumption is I can use rate limiting on the top of it to further narrow it down based on my use case. But I was not sure how this works for paid vs free account. I suspected rate limiting parameters/limits may differ for paid vs free account. I have posted this on cloudflare forum and I hope to get better understanding of this. Thanks again!